# Android code to display spinner with image and text from database

Tags: android, xml

Android code to display spinner with image and text from database i have used the code But using this i can only display text in spinner how to display both text and image from database. i have gone through many examples but all examples shows only through manually where the text and images are already there in the array list. but i want those to be extracted from database and the display in spinner just like a listview where we can display both images and text.

```
adapter1=new ArrayAdapter<String>this,R.layout.spinner_layout,R.id.txt,listItems);        
   // sp.setPrompt("Select Group");
    sp.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

But using this i can only display text in spinner how to display both text and image from database

Xml code

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_parent_rounded_corner" >

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
     android:focusable="true"
     android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
     android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/gfnam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
       android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.49"
          android:gravity="center"
       android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="Search by Group Name..."
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/search"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:background="#999900cc"
       android:textColor="#fff"
        android:text="Search"
        android:textSize="12dp" />
    </LinearLayout>  

    <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     > <!--     android:background="#FFFFFF"  -->  

      <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      >
      <Button
        android:id="@+id/addEvent"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:gravity="center"
       android:background="#990975a2"
       android:textColor="#fff"
        android:text="Select Group"
        android:textSize="12dp" />      
   <Spinner
     android:id="@+id/spinner"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="35dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:layout_weight="0.50"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
     android:background="@drawable/pic1_parent_rounded_corner"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:popupBackground="@drawable/pic1_parent_rounded_corner"
   android:textSize="13dp">
  </Spinner>       
  </LinearLayout>

 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lType"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:hint="   Write Post(Max 35 char)"
        android:maxLength="35"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
    <requestFocus />

       <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:hint="   URL"
        android:inputType="textUri"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="230dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
       android:gravity="center"
     > <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
     >  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
     > 
       <Button
            android:id="@+id/gallem"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:textSize="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gallerys"
             android:textColor="#ffffff"/> 

          <Button
            android:id="@+id/camer"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:textSize="12dp"
             android:textColor="#ffffff" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"                                                                                      android:background="@drawable/cammera"/> 
            <Button android:id="@+id/imgup"
             android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:textSize="12dp"
             android:background="@drawable/post"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
              />
          <Button
            android:id="@+id/imgcan"
             android:layout_width="60dp"
             android:layout_height="60dp"
             android:textSize="12dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
             android:background="@drawable/cancel"
           />                  
       </LinearLayout>  
     </LinearLayout>
     </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Spinner list item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">   

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spinnerTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/spinnerImages"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>    

</LinearLayout>
```

SpinnerAdapter

```
public class SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context ctx;
    private String[] contentArray;
    private Integer[] imageArray;

    public SpinnerAdapter(Context context, int resource, String[] objects,
            Integer[] imageArray) {
        super(context,  R.layout.spinner_value_layout, R.id.spinnerTextView, objects);
        this.ctx = context;
        this.contentArray = objects;
        this.imageArray = imageArray;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_value_layout, parent, false);

        TextView textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.spinnerTextView);
        textView.setText(contentArray[position]);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.spinnerImages);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageArray[position]);

        return row;    
    }    
}
```

In your activity create data and call spinner

```
 String[] textArray = { "option1", "option2", "option3", "option4" };
    Integer[] imageArray = { R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,
            R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4};

SpinnerAdapter adapter = new SpinnerAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_value_layout, textArray, imageArray);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: hii thanks for the reply... but how to do call the same image and text from database rather than from String[] textArray = { "option1", "option2", "option3", "option4" };
    Integer[] imageArray = { R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,
            R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4};

Comment: If you want to display same text and image just set static text and image in adapter `textView.setText("Sample text");` `imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);`

Comment: No i know this method actually i have a list of text and images which has to be retrived from database and show in spinner, i know the static method but dont know how to get the same through database and show in  spinner list items

Answer (score 0):

You want to use an `Async` task, which sounds difficult and complicated, but really all you have to do is:

1. Define it as a new `AsyncTask`
2. Call `onPrexecute` and include spinner in this portion
3. Call `doInBackground` with all of you image getting/text setting
4. Call `finish()` `onPostExecute`.

This will make it so everything always appears if all of the other variables (like good connectivity, etc.) are in order. 
Hope this helped you!

Comment: ya i can do so but after getting text and image through json parsing how can i display that both in  spinner view

Comment: i have used for  this code inise asynctask (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
       JSONObject c = users.getJSONObject(i);
       //ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePic);


       
       // Storing each json item in variable
       
       
        list.add(n = c.getString("grp_name1")); // from (php)
        
            
        
      }

Comment: You can call the same `spinner` that you instantiated in `onPreExecute` for `doInBackground` or before you call `finish()` `onPostExecute`

Comment: Yeah, you can probably just put the textual result of int i into the spinner before moving onto the next piece of data

Comment: I can tell that you're pretty green at this. Check out [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V4q0sTIntsk) on YouTube, he should help you greatly. Any questions after watching and following the videos let me know